# Cellular iPad-Air text message configuration

Tags: ipad

Given the following:

- iPad air with cellular modem (issued by T-mobile)
- T-mobile sim card from working telephone: re-allocated to iPad

What are the steps \ procedure to configure iPad's [iMessage](https://support.apple.com/explore/messages) to receive text messages from SIM phone number?

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: @Allan  Good question: a text message was sent to the SIM phone number and it does not show up on the Messages app

Answer (score 2):

You can't use SMS messaging on an iOS device (or any device for that matter) that doesn't connect to the GSM network.

SMS is part of the [GSM services network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_services); the "telephone" functionality of your device.  It's the network that allows you to place a call to all phones including land lines.  The iPad doesn't connect to the GSM network.

[iMessage requires a data connection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207006) (WiFi or cellular data like LTE) because they are sent and received through a server over the TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: I would love to learn more about the technical difference between how an iPad gets cellular data and iPhone gets data. Should I post a question on that @Allan?